# How do I properly split a url then get remaining parts in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of url's in a json object from `WordPress`. I want to split them by a prefix that I can see which is `https://www.example.co` then get the remaining parts like `/cat1/aa/bb/cc, /?page_id=8830, /xmlrpc.php`

```
var myUrl = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/news/why-residents/attachment/san-francisco-blog/feed/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/?page_id=8830",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 18, 2019"
  },
]
```

My current code looks like this:

```
myUrl.forEach(function(item) {
    var urlList = item.URL.split("/");
    //console.log(urlList);
    console.log("https://www.example.co/" + urlList[3]);
});
```

The code above cannot currently get the remaining parts from the prefix.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the domain from the URL, then you can use `String.prototype.replace` rather than `String.prototype.split`.

For example:

```js
const myUrl = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/news/why-residents/attachment/san-francisco-blog/feed/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/?page_id=8830",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 18, 2019"
  },
];

const paths = myUrl.map(value => value.URL.replace('https://www.example.co', ''));

console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data come from difference URL domain, you can create `URL` object and get `pathname` and `search`.

```
const paths = myUrl.map(value => new URL(value.URL).pathname + new URL(value.URL).search);
```

```js
const myUrl = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.microsoft.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.google.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/news/why-residents/attachment/san-francisco-blog/feed/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/?page_id=8830",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 18, 2019"
  },
];

const paths = myUrl.map(value => new URL(value.URL).pathname + new URL(value.URL).search);

console.log(paths);
```